# javascript - how to execute a simple GET webrequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I execute a simple webrequest in javascript.

Such as

```
var str = *whatever_comes_back_from*("search.php?term=hello");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery, or another javascript library, but instead of thinking of populating the variable then continueing with the script in a linear way, you should think in terms of a callback once the value is retrieved, because it can take a variable amount of time to retrieve the data.

This event based architecture is a feature of javascript that is rare in other programming languages.

```
$.get('search.php?term=hello', function(data){
    alert(data)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is usually handed via [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), usually abstracted via [a library that irons out the differences between browsers](http://microjs.com/#ajax) (bigger libraries that do lots of other stuff include [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).